# User Id Mismatch for Square register IOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, square-connect

I am getting the `user_id_mismatch` error code when using the SquareRegisterSDK-iOS.

I first set the client id in my initial view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SCCAPIRequest.setClientID(<my application id>)

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 18 / 255, green: 63 / 255, blue: 87 / 255, alpha: 1.0)
    pinInput.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "pin", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.25)])
}
```

and then make the request in another view controller:

```
@IBAction func purchase(_ sender: Any) {
    let amount: SCCMoney

    do {
        amount = try SCCMoney(amountCents: 2300, currencyCode: Constants.currencyCodeString)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error creating SCCMoney: \(error)")
        return
    }

    let request: SCCAPIRequest
    do {
        request = try SCCAPIRequest(
            callbackURL: URL(string:"myproject://payment-complete")!,
            amount: amount,
            userInfoString: nil,
            merchantID: <my merchant id>,
            notes: nil,
            customerID: nil,
            supportedTenderTypes: .all,
            clearsDefaultFees: false,
            returnAutomaticallyAfterPayment: true)

        do {
            try SCCAPIConnection.perform(request)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Cannot perform request: \(error)")
            return
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error SCCApiRequest: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Im not sure what user id it is looking for, unless i missed it in the docs somewhere

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I was misunderstanding what the merchant id is, and i was conflating it with square business id that is returned from `https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me`.

Setting the merchant id to `nil` in the `SCCAPIRequest` fixed my error